# Error when generating presigned url from aws s3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, fastapi

When I try to return a generate presigned url using boto3 from bucket in aws s3 and the code:

```
import fastapi
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

s3 = boto3.client("s3",
                aws_access_key_id="...",
                aws_secret_access_key="...")

BUCKET_NAME = "tayibat-files"

app = FastAPI()                      

@app.get('/{file_name}')
async def method_name(file_name: str):
try:
    url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
                    'get_object',
                    Params={'Bucket': BUCKET_NAME,
                    'Key': f"products/{file_name}"},
                    ExpiresIn=3600
                    )
except ClientError as e:
    logging.error(e)
return url
```

the get request return an url, but when I try to open it in browsers, It generate:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document 
tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC- 
SHA256.</Message>
<RequestId>ZW269CV1TAYC7CWC</RequestId>
<HostId>1yozjolBbu4difnOjjopLeOk79i34WDOFwp1VQA4Nqd0RBdLNkaOkb/uJVjFtyNu78fx06JfCbI=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: What is `file_name` in this scenario? Is it empty string?

Comment: This is the name of the file stored in the bucket (tea.jpg)

Comment: Ah, try modifying your client to include sigv4 signing e.g. `s3 = boto3.client('s3', ..., config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))`

Comment: I did and it says: <Error>
<Code>AuthorizationQueryParametersError</Code>
<Message>Error parsing the X-Amz-Credential parameter; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-3'</Message>
<Region>eu-west-3</Region>
<RequestId>5GPSH1GJPXY4PRQH</RequestId>
<HostId>O4mAHx5gyZH6s7vNBmunF80XpuPg97gah9SpvYA/9t8eEDGTVwjpzPC86EQfIgaTgY/e1k9jI+4=</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Which region is the S3 bucket actually in? You can try including that region when creating the boto3 client e.g. `s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-3', ...)`

Comment: new error: <Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIA6RGKSLTGUD2I2DE</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20220921T1322 20220921/eu-west-3/s3/aws4_request 8734dd92eb72ef830b9c2be59bf5b9322d0db566aef52fd8185805b8b6a52f39</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>753b56327963eb16e9d8820c90fae08a964802d0f227eeeebfb2d25831d5e5fa</SignatureProvided> ...

Comment: my aws region:  eu-west-3

Comment: Right, so supply the region explicitly on the client construction call and re-test.

Comment: Yes I did it before telling about the error above: <Error> <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code> <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message> <AWSAccessKeyId>AKIA6RGKSLTGUD2I2DE</AWSAccessKeyId> <StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20220921T1322 20220921/eu-west-3/s3/aws4_request 8734dd92eb72ef830b9c2be59bf5b9322d0db566aef52fd8185805b8b6a52f39</StringToSign> <SignatureProvided>753b56327963eb16e9d8820c90fae08a964802d0f227eeeebfb2d25831d5e5fa</SignatureProvided> ...

Comment: Ah, just noticed that, apologies. Are these valid credentials? Can you make other S3 API calls with this client e.g. get_object() or list_objects_v2()?

Comment: Yes, I just did     resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME)
    for obj in resp1["Contents"]:
        print(obj) ... And It prints the results just fine as: {'Key': 'products/tea.jpg', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 21, 7, 21, 16, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ETag': '"a1ae593dacfb190703c6b297a19974"', 'Size': 68034, 'StorageClass': 'STANDARD'}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not your code but your method of authentication or region.

I ran your code sample successfully:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name="<my-profile>")
client = session.client('s3')

BUCKET_NAME = "<bucket>"
file_name = "<file>"

url = client.generate_presigned_url(
    'get_object',
    Params={'Bucket': BUCKET_NAME,
            'Key': f"products/{file_name}"},
    ExpiresIn=3600
)

print(url)
```

It worked fine because the region of my bucket aligned with the region of my credentials.  When I tried to generate a presigned url from another region I got your same error:

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidRequest</Code>
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message>
<RequestId>JJPZYSMZTC7Z8H</RequestId>
<HostId>TsgdZIibKxZ4GVL3h28OJYIvh59yfgeZwVf+eGPXVEzIJsAxdp1VQL67vw20LR/r9uIBxro=</HostId>
</Error>
```